# Custom shell glob problem

Tags: c, shell, glob

I have to write a shell program in c that **doesn't use the system() function.** One of the features is that we have to be able to use wild cards. I can't seem to find a good example of how to use glob or this fnmatch functions that I have been running into so I have been messing around and so far I have a some what working blog feature (depending on how I have arranged my code).

If I have a glob variable declared as a global then the function partially works. However any command afterwards produces in error. example:

```
ls *.c
produce correct results
ls -l //no glob required
null passed through
```

so I tried making it a local variable. This is my code right now:

```
int runCommand(commandStruct * command1) {
if(!globbing)
    execvp(command1->cmd_path, command1->argv);
else{
    glob_t globbuf;
    printf("globChar: %s\n", globChar);
    glob(globChar, GLOB_DOOFFS, NULL, &globbuf);
    //printf("globbuf.gl_pathv[0]: %s\n", &globbuf.gl_pathv[0]);
    execvp(command1->cmd_path, &globbuf.gl_pathv[0]);
    //globfree(&globbuf);
    globbing = 0;
}
return 1;
```

}

When doing this with the globbuf as a local, it produces a null for globbuf.gl_path[0]. Can't seem to figure out why. Anyone with a knowledge of how glob works know what might be the cause? Can post more code if necessary but this is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works for me:

```
...
glob_t glob_buffer;
const char * pattern = "/tmp/*";
int i;
int match_count;


glob( pattern , 0 , NULL , &glob_buffer ); 
match_count = glob_buffer.gl_pathc;
printf("Number of mathces: %d \n", match_count);

for (i=0; i < match_count; i++) 
    printf("match[%d] = %s \n",i,glob_buffer.gl_pathv[i]);

globfree( &glob_buffer );
...
```

Observe that the `execvp` function expects the argument list to end with a NULL pointer, i.e. I think it will be the easiest to create your own `char ** argv` copy with all the elements from the `glob_buffer.gl_pathv[]` and a NULL pointer at the end.

Comment: According to the man page, `glob()` already makes sure to send the buffer with a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for `GLOB_DOOFFS` but you did not specify any number in `globbuf.gl_offs` saying how many slots to reserve.

Presumably as a global variable it gets initialized to 0.

Also this: `&globbuf.gl_pathv[0]` can simply be `globbuf.gl_pathv`.

And don't forget to run `globfree(globbuf)`.

I suggest running your program under `valgrind` because it probably has a number of memory leaks, and/or access to uninitialized memory.

Comment: Hrmm. Okay I guess that makes some sense with the GLOB_DOOFFS. However when I initialize it to 0 by hand as a local, it doesn't work at all either. Any suggestions one what to do there? All memory are taken care of according to valgrind. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I assume you've seen the code example at the bottom of `man glob`. Seems I was wrong about `&globbuf.gl_pathv[0]` because they do that too. Beyond that I don't know, sorry. Maybe the bug is in a piece of the code you have not included. Also, try valgrind without the `execvp` call, because that call wipes away the program, and replaces it by another, so valgrind can't find anything.

Comment: This causes a memory leak with glob because it is impossible for it to be freed after execvp is called. This is a problem indeed. Not sure how to work around this.

Comment: I don't think you should worry about it - put the `globfree()` call in your code, but comment that the code will never reach that point. This is the memory used by `argv`/`argc`, and isn't really leaked.

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for the help. got everything working now.

Comment: What was the problem? And I just realized the code actually can reach `globfree()` if the command to execute was not found, so you should handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use * style wildcards I've always found it simpler to use opendir(), readdir() and strcasestr(). opendir() opens a directory (can be ".") like a file, readdir() reads an entry from it, returns NULL at the end.  So use it like

```
struct dirent *de = NULL;
DIR *dirp = opendir(".");
while ((de = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
  if ((strcasestr(de->d_name,".jpg") != NULL) {
  // do something with your JPEG
  }
}
```

Just remember to closedir() what you opendir().  A struct dirent has the d_type field if you want to use it, most files are type DT_REG (not dirs, pipes, symlinks, sockets, etc.).

It doesn't make a list like glob does, the directory is the list, you just use criteria to control what you select from it.